# Node selenium web driver URL loop is not working

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
var serial = ["552861802186","732146914443"]
var URL = ["https://www.justdial.com/Ahmedabad/New-Shobhana-Embroidery-Opposite-Konark-Karishma-Flats-Vastrapur/079PXX79-XX79-110316110340-F9T3_BZDET?xid=QWhtZWRhYmFkIFNhcmVlIFJldGFpbGVycw==",
"https://www.justdial.com/Ahmedabad/Sukanya-Opposite-Navneet-Gala-Gurukul/079PXX79-XX79-140406171027-T1C6_BZDET?xid=QWhtZWRhYmFkIFNhcmVlIFJldGFpbGVycw=="]
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
By = webdriver.By,
until = webdriver.until;
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();
for(var i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
    driver.get(URL[i]);
    driver.wait(function () {
        driver.executeScript('return document.readyState').then(function(return_value) {
            driver.executeScript("var phone = [{ 'Name': $('.fn').text(), 'Phone': [] }]; $('ul.comp-contact > span.telnowpr > a.tel').each(function(index, el) { phone[0].Phone.push($(this).html()) }); return phone;").then(function(return_value) {
                console.log(return_value);
            }, function (err) {})
        }, function (err) {})
    }, 1);
}
```

there is 2 major problem

> (1) return value printing multiple time in the console.
>   (2) It not returning value from the first URL. It returning value only from the
>   second URL. How can I solve all this issue?